# PNG images on stack.imgur rendered incorrectly on Chrome

Tags: support, bug, images

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549878) on main, when the `PNG` file is shown implicitly (one has to open a new tab to see it), the color scheme seems to be reversed (bright $\leftrightarrow$ dark).

The same file looks perfectly fine when done inline (or reference style but explicitly displayed).

Please see my screen grab below (done inline style to avoid ambiguity).

[image]

Evidence shows that this "feature" persists when the [same file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVlnR.png) is downloaded and reuploaded (duh), and it's not just my computer but a [Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWOba.png) issue.

I understand there are numerous image encoding practices and not just a few standards, but **is this considered a bug?**

If the info is relevant, I'm running Google Chrome "Version $79.0.3945.130$ (Official Build) ($64$-bit)" on a Windows $10$ Home edition "Version $1903$ OS build $18362.657$". At this point I haven't felt the need to ask how the original image was generated.

Comment: I don't have the tools to check the png contents right now, but I suspect it might be a transparency problem. See this: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0K-YX73JpjRI/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the PNG file, I can now confirm most of the image is indeed transparent: everything except the geometric objects.

Some navigators seem to have problems showing a standalone image file (i.e. not embedded in a web page) which has transparency.

On Windows:

- Correctly shown: Firefox 73, Internet Explorer 11, Edge
- Black background: Google Chrome, Vivaldi

I think we can consider this a bug of the navigator.

It will not harm in web pages, only when showing a standalong image file, which happens quite often on MSE as newcomers seem to have a hard time importing images. It will likely only happen with images produced by software (plots, drawing), not with photos.

The solution is quite simple: either imbed the image in the web page, as should generally be done, or edit the image file: MS Paint replaces transparency with a white background, which is usually the right thing - but MS Photos fails and opens the image with a dark background too.

It's quite disturbing. PNG was invented more than 20 years ago. I remember back then graphics software did not often handle transparency very well (but some did). But having such a bug in navigators and OS software in 2020 is bewildering. Having to rely on MS Paint as a last resort is even more so.

Comment: I just tried uploading a PNG with transparency and the image was converted to a JPG after rendering the PNG on a white background. Since a PNG without transparency is brought through as a PNG, I imagine that the devs have "fixed" this by converting PNGs with transparency to JPGs.

Comment: @robjohn JPEG isn't well suited to drawings usually. Does the image suffer from lossy compression?